# Having issue with UILocalNotification custom sound

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilocalnotification

I am trying to schedule local notifications with custom alert sound. so simple I drag my alert to the app mention its name :

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate = date
    notification.alertBody = title
    notification.soundName = "yearlyReminder.caf"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Registering Notification :

```
   let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```

I also tried `WAV,MP3,AIFF,M4A` but non of these file formats worked !! my sound is under 30 seconds and tested with various formats ,but every time notification receives the sound is `UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName` What is the problem ?

> PROBLEM SOLVED: There was a problem in converted file I used another
>   converter and fixed.

Comment: Are you sure you ticked "Copy items if needed" and also target name while adding audio file into bundle?

Comment: @BhumitMehta yes i am sure

Comment: Delete your app from device, command + shift + alt +k then  command + shift +k then command b then command r. try this way.

Comment: @Hasya Tried ! nothing changed

Comment: Did you setup   let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]  and application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types) in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: @Hasya check out my edited Q

Comment: Is your file available in "Copy bundle resources" ? and "Target Membership" selected on your .caf file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117929/discussion-between-hasya-and-mc-lover).

Comment: @Mc.Lover I have same issue. Could you please tell which converter have you used? I'm using Audacity and sound doesn't play :(

Comment: @Ponf I think I used an online converter !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this it will work :

```
if let soundURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("yearlyReminder", withExtension: "caf") {
            var mySound: SystemSoundID = 0
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &mySound)
            // Play
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound);
        }
```

The best of using this approach is that the sound will play whether the user is inside the app, or the app is running in background.

Comment: `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` should I import specific framework ?

Comment: only import AVFoundation

Comment: Thank you , but PROBLEM SOLVED: There was a problem in converted file I used another converter and fixed.